# Why doesn't serial communication work on Arduino Uno r3 and ESP8266 WiFi module?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have a simple problem here. I use an ESP8266 WiFi module and an Arduino Uno r3.

What I want is to receive a serial message from the ESP8266 on the Arduino Uno.

Note: I set the upload speed of the ESP8266 to 9600.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.write("hello friend");
  delay(2000);
}
```

Arduino Uno:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); //rx, tx

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

String message = "";
boolean check = false;

void loop() {
  Serial.println(mySerial.available());
  mySerial.println("hindi nagagana");
  while (mySerial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println(mySerial.readString());
    check = true;
  }

  if (check == true) {
    Serial.println(message);
  }

  delay(200);
}
```

Or any idea on how to control the Arduino Uno via the internet, such as a simple LED blink?

I used Firebase for databases an I plan to use ReactJs for webApp/Native App (nodeJs).

Comment: you print the empty String `message` forever once something is received on mySerial

Comment: Are you sure you have tx connected to rx and vice versa?  You could use the serial monitor to test each half in isolation.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should change `Serial.write()` to `Serial.print()` because `Serial.write()` is for send data as bytes or series of bytes and `Serial.print()` send as human-readable text.
Reference:
Serial.write()
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/
Serial.print()
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/
esp 8266 code:

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
    Serial.print("hello friend");
    delay(2000);
 
 }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering my question it really help but the thing is , its not working T_T is there any library or board installation do i need to install?? Im ran out of google stuff on the internet

Comment: `write` and `print` are same for string

Comment: Can you add your wiring diagram into question?